# Mapping formula elements to terms

Tags: r

When generating terms from a formula, R seems to sometimes change the order of the variables:

```r
> terms(~ strata:dayname:hour_local + treat_assign:dayname:hour_local) |> labels()

[1] "strata:dayname:hour_local"       "dayname:hour_local:treat_assign"
```

Is there any way to either prevent this reordering from happening, or to map between elements in the formula and the terms?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `reformulate`:

R will order the terms alphabetically by default. We could control the order of the terms manually with `reformulate()`.

```
reformulate(c("strata:dayname:hour_local", "treat_assign:dayname:hour_local"), response = ".")
```

```
~ strata:dayname:hour_local + treat_assign:dayname:hour_local
```